# LinearLayout inside ScrollView is autoscrolled to bottom

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview, autoscroll

I've got a ScrollView which occupies the bottom half of the screen.
Inside this ScrollView a put a LinearLayout (vertical) with a lot of content. 
When I start the activity, the content somewhy automatically scrolls itself down so that it starts at the top of the window. But I need it to start at the top of the ScrollView (i.e. at the center of the window).
What am I doing wrong?
[image]

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="ru.intrigue.activities.EditActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:visibility="visible">

 </RelativeLayout>

<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView2"
        android:background="@color/colorDarkBack">

           <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="10dp">


                 <!-- content -->

          </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: post the relevant code as well

Comment: How have you set your `ScrollView` to occupy just half of your screen?

Comment: the problem with your code is that you are using `match_parent` for your `ScrollView` height. See my answer below to see how to do it properly.

Comment: have you solved your issue?

Answer (score 1):

you can do like below:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="1">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.45"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/frag_home_iv_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/demo" />

</LinearLayout>

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.55"
    android:fadeScrollbars="false">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.26"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="@dimen/padding_5dp"
            android:weightSum="1">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.3"
                android:src="@drawable/demo" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/fragment_home_tv"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.7"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding_5dp"
                android:text="@string/demo"
                android:textColor="@color/BlackColor" />
        </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>


</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem solve by below code :

When open your activity call below code:

```
your_scroll_view.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            your_scroll_view.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
                        }
                    });
```

Best of luck

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the desired results by using `layout_weight` property:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <!-- your content here-->

    </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <!-- your content here-->

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Let me know if it helped you.

Comment: I'm afraid it didn't. I did like you said and still the same behavior.

Comment: [Edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38627466/edit) your answer with the updated code